# Stacking images on top of eachother

Tags: php, css, image

I have a PHP site that displays a table of images.
Each image has a "backdrop" to them that is user defined. So, users can say "I want the red backdrop" and all images will be displayed, with a 10 pixel border of their color.

Also, it is a staticy backdrop.

To accomplish this, I first echo the static image, then the user color image, then the table image.

```
echo "<img src='Static.jpg' width='60' height='60' />";
echo "<img src='User$userColor.jpg'  width='60' height='60' />";
echo "<img alt='TableImage' width='50' height='50' />";
```

Currentley, I push the latter two images up by attaching this to them:

```
style='position:relative; top:-55px; margin-bottom: -55px;'
```

This seems very hacky. Is there a nice CSS way I can stack the images, so that when I change the size or order I don't have to scan and edit the stylings of every image?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but instead of using an image to create the 10px border around the static image, why not just use CSS by adding a class to each image you want the border?

```
.staticImage { border: 10px solid <?php print $color; ?>; }
```

You could store the color of border they want in a cookie for example.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
<img alt='TableImage' width='50' height='50' style="border: 10px solid $userColor"/>
```